# Can I trigger an animation when an element reaches half way in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, triggers, intersection-observer

(JavaScript)
I can see that it is possible to trigger an animation using an IntersectionObserver when an element enters and leaves the viewport - but is there a way to trigger an animation when an element reaches half way in the view port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```js
new IntersectionObserver(yourAnimation, {rootMargin: "0px 0px -50% 0px"})
```

your element will be intersecting when it enters the top half of the viewport. basically adding a minus margin of half its height to the bottom edge of your root (here viewport)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(elment.offsetLeft==window.offsetWidth) {startAnimation()}
// or element.offsetTop and window.offsetHeight
//you should write the startAnimation function, it not a built-in function
```